# Can using context in helper class cause memory leak in android

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

Can using context in helper class cause memory leak in android

I have a helper class with the following method

```
public class HelperClass {
        private Context context;

        public HelperClass(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
       public void Addfiles(Context context, String Filename) {
            try {
                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                File f = new File(Filename);
                Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }
```

In my MainActivity I want to call it like this

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HelperClass h = new HelperClass(this);
        h.Addfiles(this,Filename);
    }
}
```

I want to know can using context like this cause memory leaks , and if so , how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - strictly in the case above, no, since MyActivity won't be destroyed while in "onCreate"

**Long answer:**

Typically memory leaks happen when an object cannot be garbage collected because something still references it, when the garbage collector runs.
In your case, the activity is just being created, and your primary concern is whether leaks can occur, since `HelperClass` holds a reference to it.

First of all, in normal conditions (excepting when AOS might kill your app) `MainActivity` is guaranteed to not get garbage collected before its `onDestroy` method will be called. This is because until then (and possibly for some time after that - not really relevant) it will be referenced by the Android Framework itself.

`HelperClass` on the other hand, is a local variable inside `onCreate`. After `onCreate` will finish, `HelperClass` might be garbage collected at any point, since it won't have any object referencing it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352561/2220337)). So the chances of `HelperClass` being GC'd before `onDestroy` is called are quite high. If this happens then there will be no reference to `MainActivity` --> no leaks.

Event if `HelperClass` won't be garbage collected until `onDestroy` is called on `MainActivity`, you still won't have leaks since the garbage collector is smart enough to be able to clean up cyclic references.

What needs to happen for leaks to occur is that an object which outlives your `Activity` will hold a reference to it, or its context.

Assume your code would be like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final HelperClass h = new HelperClass(this);

    //does some work on a background thread, gets notified at some 
    //point in the future, through the callback, when the work 
    //has completed     
    longLivedComponent.doSomeBackgroundWork(new OnWorkFinishedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onWorkFinished(){
            h.Addfiles(this, filename);
        }

    });
}
```

Now, let's also assume the following sequence of events:

1. User opens app, `MainActivity`#1 is created, its `onCreate` is called
2. `doSomeBackgroundWork` is called, background work is started. When the background work finishes, your helper (which has a reference to `MainActivity`#1) will have to do some work.
3. User rotates device, an orientation change occurs.
4. `MainActivity` is recreated by Android. `MainActivity`#1 is destroyed (i.e. `onDestroy` will be called), and a new `MainActivity`#2 will be created
5. Steps 1,2 will happen for `MainActivity`#2 i.e. `doSomeBackgroundWork` will be called again, from `MainActivity`#2. (strictly speaking, this step isn't really relevant, but nevertheless)
6. The Garbage Collector runs.
7. The background work started by `MainActivity`#1 at step **#2** finishes.

Normally, at step **#6** the memory occupied by `MainActivity`#1 would be freed, as `MainActivity`#1 was destroyed.

However, in situation described here, the `OnWorkFinishedListener` needs to be persisted by `longLivedComponent` until the background work finishes. The listener has a reference to both your `MainActivity`#1 (implicit anonymous inner class reference to its parent class), and to your `HelperClass` instance, which also contains an instance to `MainActivity`#1.

When the garbage collector sees this at step **#6**, it assumes that `MainActivity`#1 is still alive & used since there stil are objects pointing to it. Because of this, it doesn't reclaim its memory, you'll end up with two instances of `MainActivity` in memory and a leak occurs.

To prevent this, you could:

- Use the application context instead of the activity context, in classes that will be used by long-lived objects. Also, in your case you don't need anything specific to the activity itself
- Make sure that any long-lived objects (like longLivedComponent in our case), or objects shared between activities, won't store references to an `Activity` or its `Context`, after `onDestroy()` has been called on said `Activity`

Hope this helps

Comment: really useful explanation

Comment: So by overriding `onDestroy()` and setting `h = null` and `longLivedComponent = null` before `super.onDestroy()` we can prevent such a memory leak that might occur in the second scenario. Correct?